# Duplicate previous questions or not

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

I encountered this two questions that I answered:

- [What are the patterns for the Northern animals?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/166082/43105)
- [What are the patterns for finding Savannah animals?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/166081/43105)

Then I decided to create an question/answer for each area of the game. There is eight areas. So I thought it was better to create only one question/answer to solve this issue:

[What are the patterns for the animals in the different areas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166156/what-are-the-patterns-for-the-animals-in-the-different-areas/166157#166157)

Should I mark as duplicate the previous ones, delete the newer one and create individual answers for each area or...?

Comment: Assuming all three questions are adequately answered, I'd close the more specific ones as dupes of the more generic one?

Comment: This is very strongly related to [What do you do when a question is asked which is a collection of other asked questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-is-asked-which-is-a-collection-of-other-asked-que). The biggest difference here is that this one adds a lot of new information, whereas the one I posted consolidated only questions that had already been asked. I'm currently not sure where I stand on it.

Comment: I have the information, so I have to know if I should create one global question (despite the two individual questions) or eight different separate questions, basically.

Comment: Fundamentally the problem with saying "Oh, here'a specific question, let me broaden it up and close the original one" is that in many ways, you make it harder for the original asker to get an answer, because now instead of a potential answerer needing to know about just the one set of animals, they need to be able to know about *all* sets of animals to answer the question. That's one reason why I don't like the idea of expanding a question and retroactively duping the original. In practice, both have already been answered, so it's not much of a concern in this case.

Comment: But I don't think anyone is considering closing your question, so really it's an argument of whether the originals should be closed. And as much as we love policy debates and arguments over whether or not something should be closed, I don't think 99.999% of the people who visit the site will ever be affected by the ultimate decision in this particular case. I'm leaning towards just leaving everything open. Which is to say, I'm not bothering to go cast any close votes. But if someone else does, I'm not going to bother to case reopen votes, either.

Comment: In short, no one really seems to care either way. Do what you want. :)

Comment: @Sterno Thanks for your support